# Module not generated in pub/ folder, Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, frontend, bug, static-content-deploy, pub

**Hello!**

I have Magento version 2.3.3.

I run:

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> bin/magento bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

And permissions for folders:

But after commands in **pub/static/frontend** folder i not find module with my styles and with my JS code.

How i can fix it?

Please, help me)

Comment: Is your website has multiple stores?

Comment: @MagentoUser, no - my website - single store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I resolved problem!**

My folder that I searched in the folder **pub/static** located in **app/design** and Magento 2.3.3 will not use this code unless it is a module.

Therefore, I need to transfer my code to **app/code/[Alias]**.

*Hope this information helps someone.*

Answer (score 1):

**1. Put your Custom JS file in the following directory**

> app/code/Vendor/YourModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/your_js_file_name.js

-> And your require-config.js file is in directory

```
var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                myjs: 'Vendor_YourModuleName/js/your_js_file_name'
            }
        }
    };
```

**2. Delete Generated Files, Sessions & Caches:**

> YOUR_MAGENTO2_ROOT/var/cache/ ****DELETE ALL****
>
> YOUR_MAGENTO2_ROOT/var/page_cache/ ****DELETE ALL****
>
> YOUR_MAGENTO2_ROOT/var/session/ ****DELETE ALL****
>
> YOUR_MAGENTO2_ROOT/var/view_preprocessed/ ****DELETE ALL****

-> Also, remove everything including old generated static files from below path except **.htaccess**:

> YOUR_MAGENTO2_ROOT/pub/static/ ****DELETE ALL**** ***EXCEPT .HTACCESS***
>
> YOUR_MAGENTO2_ROOT/generated/code/ ****DELETE ALL****
>
> YOUR_MAGENTO2_ROOT/generated/metadata/ ****DELETE ALL****

**3. Open terminal and run following commands:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
chmod -R 777 var/* pub/* generated/*
```

Now check your modules js files are loaded under pub/static/